# DynamoDB: Query not working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

This is the query:

```
                var params = {
                    TableName : "events",
                    KeyConditionExpression: "event = :event",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":event": "florida"
                    }
                };
                db.query(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                    else     console.log(data);
                })
```

This is the error:

> message: 'Query condition missed key schema element: id', code:
>   'ValidationException',

What am I doing wrong here?

Table looks like this:

> id division_id event
>
> 1491934519379 111222 florida
>   1491934895527 222111 florida
>   1491936271559 232123 earthquake
>   1491936037958 543335 los angeles
>   1491936037957 554334 los angeles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to query by a non-key value (`event`).

You'll need to either query by `id`, or set up a [global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) (GSI), using your `event` column as the index hash key.

You can create a GSI by calling [UpdateTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html).

Once you create the index, you'll be able to call [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) with your `IndexName`, to query records by `event`.